# Duplicate column error on UNION of two tables with JOINS mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE NameWithAddress
  ( 
    Name                    VARCHAR(255),
    Address                 VARCHAR(255)
  ); 

  CREATE TABLE NamesWithCountry
  ( 
    Name                   VARCHAR(255),
    Country                VARCHAR(255)
  );
```

I want to merge both tables, so matching rows on name are joined, but unmatched rows from both tables are still included in the query

I have a query that returns the results I want:

```
SELECT *
FROM `NameWithAddress`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `NamesWithCountry` ON `NameWithAddress`.`Name` = `NamesWithCountry`.`Name`
UNION SELECT *
FROM `NameWithAddress`
RIGHT OUTER JOIN `NamesWithCountry` ON `NameWithAddress`.`Name` = `NamesWithCountry`.`Name`
WHERE `NameWithAddress`.`Name` IS NULL
```

But when I try and select the result of this query, I get a duplicate column error. This is how I am performing the SELECT:

```
SELECT T.* FROM (
SELECT *
FROM `NameWithAddress`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `NamesWithCountry` ON `NameWithAddress`.`Name` = `NamesWithCountry`.`Name`
UNION SELECT *
FROM `NameWithAddress`
RIGHT OUTER JOIN `NamesWithCountry` ON `NameWithAddress`.`Name` = `NamesWithCountry`.`Name`
WHERE `NameWithAddress`.`Name` IS NULL) T
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you would do this with a `full join`, but MySQL doesn't support `FULL JOIN`.  I would recommend:

```
SELECT n.name, nwa.address, nwc.country
FROM (SELECT Name
      FROM NameWithAddress
      UNION   -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      SELECT Name
      FROM NamesWithCountry
     ) n LEFT JOIN
     NameWithAddress nwa
     ON nwa.name = n.name LEFT JOIN
     NamesWithCountry nwc
     ON nwc.name = n.name;
```

If you know that names are never duplicated within either table, then:

```
select name, max(address) as address, max(country) as country
from ((select name, address, null as country
       from namewithaddress
      ) union all
      (select name, null as address, country
       from namewithcountry
      )
     ) n
group by name;
```

I strongly discourage the use of the `union` with `left join` and `right join`.  That is sort of an approximation to a `full join` under some circumstances.  However, it is more performance-intensive than these methods and the subtle differences from a real `full join` can be difficult to figure out (and correct).

Answer (score 1):

You need to rename one of the `Name` columns or omit them:

```
SELECT T.* FROM (
SELECT `NameWithAddress`.*, `NamesWithCountry`.`Country`
FROM `NameWithAddress`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `NamesWithCountry` ON `NameWithAddress`.`Name` = `NamesWithCountry`.`Name`
UNION SELECT `NameWithAddress`.*, `NamesWithCountry`.`Country`
FROM `NameWithAddress`
RIGHT OUTER JOIN `NamesWithCountry` ON `NameWithAddress`.`Name` = `NamesWithCountry`.`Name`
WHERE `NameWithAddress`.`Name` IS NULL) T
```

Comment: I am getting the following error with your SQL:

" ER_WRONG_NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS_IN_SELECT: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the SQL for the second part of the UNION. Fixed.